# Check if today's date falls between two other dates without using the year

Tags: javascript

Using JavaScript to write some code. What I need to do is check to see if todays date falls in between two other dates, all without using the year.
Here is what I have, but I know I am doing a bunch wrong. lol. Appreciate any help.
I see a solution for PHP, but I don't know if that translates to JavaScript:
[Check if todays date is between two other dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26999831/check-if-todays-date-is-between-two-other-dates)

`var CurrentDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(),  "MMM d");
if (CurrentDate > "Jun 21" && CurrentDate < "Dec 25") {
do stuff}`

Comment: convert all dates to the epoch timestamps and then check if today's date falls in the required range

Comment: Well I started with: Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(),  "MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss");
But didnt want to use the year. Im a total noob, so must be something else I am doing wrong.

Comment: `momentjs` this library may help you. Check out [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/)

Comment: Take care in spelling “JavaScript” to avoid Search collision with “Java”.

Comment: Im doing this inn Google apps script editor, should have mentioned that. Don't know what that changes.

Answer (score 0):

Since your dates all have the "MMM d" format, this works:

```js
function testDate(dateStr, lowerBound, upperBound) {
  const leapYearStr = ', 2004';
  const date = new Date(dateStr + leapYearStr);
  const lower = new Date(lowerBound + leapYearStr);
  const upper = new Date(upperBound + leapYearStr);
  return lower < date && date < upper;
}

console.log(testDate('Feb 29', 'Feb 28', 'Mar 1'))
```

The string ", 2004" is used to convert the "MMM d" format date into a date in the year 2004, which is a leap year (so that "Feb 29" is also supported).